# Android Studio and emulator in split view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

How to start android emulator to use android studio and emulator in split view like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAa3n.jpg)

Comment: If not side by side, at least the emulator should float over the android studio, it used to happen in Windows and Linux by default but I am yet to find this feature on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Close all existing emulators. Go to File > Setting > Tasks > Emulator > uncheck "launch in tool window" > "OK"

Now run the emulator and it should show up outside Android Studios.
You can run multiple devices to show the emulators side by side.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3hyNE2D71g

Comment: It's Setting > Tools not Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for. But in settings you can enable "always run emulator on top".

Answer (score -2):

You can find here some tips to be more productive with android studio :

https://medium.com/better-programming/my-productive-android-studio-setup-9dd3774a3b91

And here are the steps to do it :
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#run-emulator-studio